# Send text field value using href to php

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have to send text field value using href to php is something like below. But it is not correct way. Can anyone please give me any solution?

```
<input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">
<a href="test.php?id=javascript:document.getElementById('myText').value;">
<input type="button" value="Click"></a>
```

Comment: that won't do anything - place it inside a form.. also I'd recommend using `$_POST` over `$_GET` - for me `$_POST` is cleaner and doesn't make the url look weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">
<a href="test.php" onclick="this.href = this.href +'?' + document.getElementById('myText').value;">test</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put content inside a form. You can also change the `button` type input to a `submit` type, this way the form is sent automatically on click.

```
<form method="POST" action="yourURL.php">
    <input type="text" id="myText" name="myElement" value="Mickey">
    <a href="test.php?id=javascript:document.getElementById('myText').value;">
    <input type="submit" value="Click"></a> 
</form>
```

More information on forms: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Form)

Whether you use `GET` or `POST` as a method, you'll be able to access the content of the form through PHP variables: `$_GET`, `$_POST` or the generic `$_REQUEST`.
More information in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

**Note**: PHP uses the `name` attribute of your HTML elements for those variables. Make sure to add this attribute to your HTML elements otherwise you'll have a hard time getting a value from `$_REQUEST['myText']`. I added the attribute holding the value "myElement" in the above code. It is accessible through PHP by typing `$_REQUEST['myElement']`.

Content sent through `GET` method is visible in the URL,
 like this: `www.example.com/test.php?var1=test&var2=test`